# Caching in Android

Tags: android, json, caching

I'm currently developing an android app in which I'm dealing with php files that returns json, the json then gets parsed and is used to fill up an arraylist of different objects.

What I'm trying to do is, I want to cache these objects in case of no internet so I can reload them and make the application useable offline.

Currently I have 2 solutions for this:

A) Make an SQLite database and creare tables with the same structure as the objects I'm trying to cache and then reload them on startup

B) Save the JSON strings inside the shared prefs and parse them on startup.

I didn't really find any best practices or tutorials when I came across data caching so I'm lost now and I have no idea what to do. So if you guys can please help out I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following talk interesting:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

As you can see, a lot of scaffolding goes into the ContentProvider approach. For a very simple app, it can be acceptable to just cache some JSON in a SharedPreferences. However, as your app becomes more complex, the advantages of the ContentProvider will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use files instead of sqlite and shared preferences.

Shared prefrences is using for small data.

Sqlite is using when you need to make queries on stored data.

So I think it's better to cache in files, or if you are using something like retrofit or any network lib you can check if they support caching and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not option B. Shares preferences are not suitable for storing large amounts of data. It's XML so cannot be queried like Sqlite. The time to retrieve a single item will increase linearly with the amount of data stored. Secondly JSON will have special character these will need to be escaped which means the storage size will increase even more.

There is however an option C. Using cache files. This approach and other store options available to you are described in the [google developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and this is essential reading.

So in summary: you options are to parse the JSON and store it in sqlite or to save the json as a file in the cache directory.